# Create PDF from MS Publisher 2010 with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, office-automation, publisher, ms-publisher

Can I someone helps me to create a .pdf file from a .pub by using the Automation of MS Publisher?

I cannot find any kind of sample about this.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a simple example using the [Microsoft Office Interop assemblies](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508).  If you have Office installed, you won't need to install the redistributable.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.Interop.Publisher

$pubFile = 'C:\users\jscott\desktop\Publication1.pub'
$pdfFile = 'C:\users\jscott\desktop\Publication1.pdf'

$pubApp = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Interop.Publisher.ApplicationClass
$pubDoc = $pubApp.Open($pubFile)

# http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff939864.aspx
$pubDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat(
    [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Publisher.PbFixedFormatType]::pbFixedFormatTypePDF,
    $pdfFile
)

$pubDoc.Close()
$pubApp.Quit()
```

Comment: Hey Scott.. Thank!!! This method was the only one able to make a several page PDF document from "Merged Publication".

Comment: @Dominique Glad it worked for you, I'd not worked with Powershell and Interop before so I wanted to see if/how it could be done. If this answer resolves your issue, please consider [marking the answer accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).